# PDF Selection Issues

Tags: pdf

I am trying to highlight some text in the a pdf generated with latex, however sometimes it misbehaves and selects an entire region. Below is a gif which shows the effect I'm having (I tried to scroll to "remove" the blue selection which was left over). Is this a problem with the generation of the pdf? or perhaps macs "preview" app?

[image]

Edit: I have tried this in the "skim" app on mac and have the same problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I like the way you have illustrated your problem.

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure since I'm not a Mac user, but did you try another PDF viewer? That would be my first suggestion because I've never noticed anything like this in my LaTeX documents.

Comment: Hello! Yes I do have this problem in the "Skim" app as well.

Comment: Can someone tell me why this was put on hold? Obviously the problem is in the *generation* of the pdf which is a tex issue

Comment: This issue is to do with the algorithms the PDF viewers use to determine where lines of text are. TeX can't influence that, so it's really a viewer issue.

Comment: @JosephWright, I have read and highlighted many different PDFs, and tex generated PDFs seem to cause the huge difficulty. Does anyone know of anyway a tex generator could help mitigate this? Has no one else in the tex community encountered and/or fixed this?

Comment: I can't really believe that tex can't in some way help PDF generators by creating "selection box helpers" around math enviorments